# Defining prefixes for regular expressions

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

When dealing with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581932/showing-that-the-language-of-prefixes-operatornamepre-mathcal-l-is-regular) question, I came to realize that I'm not sure how sensible it is to define prefixes for regular expressions. So far I've run into  two sorts of prefix definitions, one for strings or words, and one for languages:

> Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet. The *prefix* of a word  or a string $x\in\Sigma^\ast$, the Kleene- or concatenation closure over the alphabet,
>   is defined as follows:
>   $$
> \operatorname{pre} x = \{x[1:i] \mid i \in\{1,\ldots, |x|\}\},
> $$
>   where the left associative slice operator $(\cdot)[m:n]$ inclusively returns the characters between the indices $m$ and $n$ in its argument.
>
> The prefix language $\operatorname{pre}\mathcal L$ is then defined using words prefixes:
>   $$
> \operatorname{pre}\mathcal L = \{ x  \in \operatorname{pre} y \mid y \in \mathcal L \}\,.
> $$

Now this is all fine and good, but if one wished to check whether a certain type of language (such as the prefix one) was regular, one would have to come up with a regular expression for each of the 6 types of languages present in the recursive definition of regular languages. But how might those be defined?

The problem is, for a regular expression such as $\alpha\beta(\gamma\delta)\epsilon \in\operatorname{RE}(\Sigma)$, the set of regular expressions that can be generated using the alphabet $\Sigma$, we can't just take an arbitrary amount of characters off the end of it. This is because it might result in a situation like $\alpha\beta(\gamma$, where the the left parenthesis has been left unmatched by a right one, therefore making this regular expression invalid: it cannot generate a regular language based on the definition.

This has left me wondering, how might prefixes of regular expressions be defined sensibly, or is that even necessary or useful?

Comment: I think it is neither necessary nor useful. It is much more natural to first define the prefixes of a word, then extend this operator to languages and finally prove that the set of prefixes of the words of a regular language is a regular language.

Comment: $\newcommand{\lang}{\mathcal{L}}$ And the proof is done by just using the definition and known properties of regular languages $\lang$. No need to use induction on regular expressions or anything.

Comment: Since you seems to be interested in the formal aspects of language theory, you may consider the notions of *rational* and *recognisable* subsets of a monoid (which are not equivalent in general, but are equivalent in a free monoid). One can also define a notion of prefix in a monoid. If I am not wrong, if $S$ is a recognisable subset of a monoid, then $\text{Pref}(S)$ is also recognisable, but  I don't think that rational subsets are closed under Pref.